# Query MySQL to show users post in PHP - Not sure how to formulate query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is my existing code from a tutorial:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo WORDING_EDIT_USER_DATA; ?></legend>
    <p><?php echo WORDING_YOU_ARE_LOGGED_IN_AS . '<b>' . $_SESSION['user_name']; ?></b></p><hr/>

    <p>$_SESSION['user_id'] = <?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?></p>
    <p>$_SESSION['user_name'] = <?php echo $_SESSION['user_name']; ?></p>
    <p>$_SESSION['user_email'] = <?php echo $_SESSION['user_email']; ?></p>
    <p>$_SESSION['user_access_level'] = <?php echo $_SESSION['user_access_level']; ?></p>
    <p>$_SESSION['user_logged_in'] = <?php echo $_SESSION['user_logged_in']; ?></p><hr/>

    <p><?php echo WORDING_PROFILE_PICTURE . '<br/><img src="' . $login->getGravatarImageUrl() ; ?>" /></p>
</fieldset><br/>
<a href="?logout"><?php echo WORDING_LOGOUT; ?></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="?edit"><?php echo WORDING_EDIT_USER_DATA; ?></a>
<?php echo (ALLOW_ADMIN_TO_REGISTER_NEW_USER && $_SESSION['user_access_level'] == 255 ? '<br/><a href="?register">'. WORDING_REGISTER_NEW_ACCOUNT .'</a>' : ''); ?>
```

This is the query I want to do on [**this schema**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/304e51/2):

```
SELECT item_title, item_location, item_datetime
FROM item
WHERE user_id = 1;
```

I'm fairly new to this but this is what I was trying, in order to show the post items which belong to that user who is logged in:

```
<?php

$result = mysql_query('SELECT item_title, item_location, item_datetime
FROM item WHERE user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'] ;');
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

?>
```

I haven't been able to make much progress in making this query work or this code run. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong please?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: if you are getting mysql error then try to print your query and check if user id is showing or not

Comment: check your quotation marks, your query should be like `"SELECT item_title, item_location, item_datetime
FROM item WHERE user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'] ;"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the main boundaries with double qoutes

```
mysql_query('SELECT item_title, item_location, item_datetime
FROM item WHERE user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'] ;');
```

to

```
mysql_query("SELECT item_title, item_location, item_datetime
FROM item WHERE user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'] ;");
```

Comment: How come the other answer has a full stop in front of the $_SESSION and yours doesn't? Does it make a difference?

Comment: @Jimmy ask google....Double quote strings displays a host of escaped characters (including some regexes), and `variables` in the strings are evaluated. Use double quotes in PHP to avoid having to use the period to separate code.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your query by this one and try :

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT item_title, item_location, item_datetime
FROM item WHERE user_id ='.$_SESSION['user_id']);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT item_title, item_location, item_datetime
FROM item WHERE user_id =  " .$_SESSION['user_id']. " ;");
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

?>
```

Anyway, you should escape the variable `$_SESSION['user_id']`, to prevent SQL injection.

Here is some of the official documentation:

http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php